# Questions about OpenVPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, openvpn

So, I have an OpenVPN server on Windows Server 2008.
Here are the settings (sorry, it's Russian, but I think it's understandable)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZLu.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtOon.jpg

It is a VPS, so I can buy another IP address for clients. Right now I need to make following: client connects to server, which has 46.161.0.183, and then gets 46.161.0.185 when browsing the web.

What do I need to change or add to configs ? I'm sure the thing is in several lines

**server config**

```
dev               tun
port              7777
proto             udp
server            46.161.0.0 255.255.255.0
push              "route 46.161.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway"
client-to-client
tls-server
dh C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh1024.pem
ca C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt
cert C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.crt
key C:\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.key
client-config-dir C:\\OpenVPN\\ccd
comp-lzo
keepalive         10 120
tun-mtu           1500
mssfix            1450
persist-key
persist-tun
verb              3
```

**client's config**

```
remote 46.161.0.183
port 7777
client
float
dev tun0
ping 10
comp-lzo
proto udp 
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
ns-cert-type server
route 46.161.0.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
pull
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit.  I am confused about what you mean when you say 'I added the 46.161.0.185 address in network settings`.  Which network settings?  On which computer?

Comment: In advanced tab here http://www.tp-link.com/resources/uploadfiles/images/image005an.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your shoes I would probably setup an client config dir on the server.

Then I would setup a config for your client that would look something like this.

```
ifconfig-push 46.161.0.185 46.161.0.186
push "route 46.161.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: 192.168.64.186 - what does this stand for ?

Comment: It stands for 'copy-paste' error on my part.  Corrected.

Comment: I'm afraid that your config doesn't work. Client connects, but internet doesn't work, OpenVPN GUI on client only says that his IP address is 46.161.0.185. I need to change, like, real address, not the virtual address of client.

Comment: When I connect to server with configs that I provided in my question, client connects, then when I go to whatsmyip.com on client machine it says 46.161.0.183, but I need 46.161.0.185

Comment: The address assigned to the tunnel interface is perfectly real.  As for what it doesn't work.  Something is wrong on your network, and i don't have enough information to make a guess.  Getting routing right can be tricky.

Comment: But when I connect, I have 46.161.0.5, and when I go to whatsmyip.com it says 46.161.0.183. What information do I need to provide ?

Comment: I need the client to have OpenVPN address 46.161.0.5, but when it goes to net it has to be 46.161.0.185

Comment: Start by updating your question.  Describe your network.  Because you are really confusing me.  In your question you have two different netmasks mentioned.  You seem to be trying to used a routed-mode VPN, but you seem to be trying to configure addresses as if it was a bridge.  I simply am not following How you imagine your network should look, and so on.  What you have described doesn't really make sense.  Try to read through your question from the perspective of someone who doesn't know your network.